# Range text selection with html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have issue with range selection, i saw some of the ans in stack over flow, I tried some thing, is not working.

The issue

The text is like below which will have the text with html tags

**Test**

The function should select only the text in side the html tags

I tried following but it is not working

```
function makeSelection() {
    var start = 3;
    var end = 9;
    var child = 2;

    var parent = document.getElementById('data');
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(parent.childNodes[child], start);
    range.setEnd(parent.childNodes[child], end);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);   
}
```

will be adding html tags dynamically to the div, the value is present at the center like

**Test**

The function should select only text Test. Please give some input to solve this issue